# Цепной вызов функций у наследников абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, виртуальная-функция

Здравствуйте. В общем захотелось мне сделать так, чтобы можно было у объектов вызывать функции "цепочкой", то есть вот так:

```
window1.SetTitle("My Program")
    ->SetSize({ 640,480 })
    ->SetPosition({ 100,100 })
    ->SetClosesProgram(true)
    ->Show();
```

Для этого, я в каждой функции возвращаю указатель на текущий объект (то есть делаю `return this`).

Все бы хорошо, но вот настало время наследования. У меня есть абстрактный класс `Control`, с одним полностью виртуальным методом и еще с набором базовых методов (таких как `SetText` и прочих), все эти методы выглядят примерно вот так:

```
Control* Control::SetSomething(int something)
{
    //Тут оснвной код метода

    return this;
}
```

Но дело в том, что от этого класса будут наследоваться другие классы (Такие как `Label`, `Button`, `TextBox` и т.д), при этом у них могут быть еще какие-то свои методы, которых в базовом нет. И вот когда будет создан объект, например класса `Label` (который наследуется от абстрактного класса `Control`), то все эти базовые методы, которые будут унаследованы от `Control`, будут отдавать указатель типа `Control*` а никак не `Label*`, что не позволит в полной мере осуществить "цепной вызов". Нужно тогда все эти базовые методы делать виртуальными, и переопределять в каждом наследнике, ну а это делает наследование бессмысленным.

Вопрос: Можно ли подобное как-то реализовать в С++? Может есть какие-то иные способы? Может хитрости с каким-нибудь виртуальным переопределением операторов? Хотелось бы узнать как это сделать правильно. За ранее благодарю.

Comment: Так ведь функции виртуальные, они разберутся, какой *реальный* тип скрывается за `this`. Что-то я никак не врублюсь в вашу проблему. Вы пробовали, и не работает? Покажите пример.

Comment: Может передавать параметры в конструктор? Или делать специальный класс чисто для параметров?

Comment: Не вижу, почему переопределение **делает наследование бессмысленным**. Наследование - это отнюдь **не** повторное использование **кода класса**, это - повторное использование **кода для работы с классом**, который благодаря этому может получать наследника вместо базового класса.

Comment: @Harry Наследование будет не только бессмысленным, но и потенциально невозможным, так как у каких-то классов-наследников могут быть одноименные методы с одинаковыми параметрами, но разными возвращаемыми значениями, которые не удастся запихнуть в базовый класс.

Comment: @VTT, передавать имя класса наследника в конструктор и одновременно указатель на него? То есть это должен быть шаблонный конструктор?

Comment: Если вам нужна красота кода, придётся после виртуальных вызовов писать переопределение static_cast. Но для оптимизации скорости проги лучше писать вызовы отдельно obj.meth;obj.meth;... тогда будет меньше мороки ассемблеру возится с возвращаемыми значениями.

Comment: @VTT Не могу понять, зачем вы собираетесь запихивать все в базовый класс? Он на то и базовый, чтобы содержать только общую функциональность. Нет, конечно, тут недавно кто-то не то самолет порождал из аэропорта, не то факультет из студента - но мы же о корректном применении языка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, большое спасибо VTT и остальным за подсказки и советы. В итоге нашел, может быть немного извращенное, но все решение. Если честно не знаю, насколько это хорошо с точки зрения "правильности кода" и эффективности, если увидите в этом что-то вопиющее - буду рад критике и другим ответам, но суть примерно такая:

Базовый класс (который абстрактный) я делаю шаблонным, в шаблоне передается имя класса наследника, а одним из параметров конструктора является указатель на объект наследника. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
template <class Derived>
class WQUERY_API ControlBase
{
private:
    Derived * pDerived_;                     // Указатель на наследника

public:
    ControlBase(Derived * pDerived):pDerived_(pDerived)
```

А базовые методы, которые по задумке наследуются для всех элементов управления, выглядят вот так:

```
Derived* SetText(const std::string &title)
{
    if (this->hWnd_)
    {
        SetWindowTextA(this->hWnd_, title.c_str());
    }

    return this->pDerived_;
}
```

Далее, делаю объявление класса-наследника вот таким образом:

```
class Button;
template class WQUERY_API ControlBase<Button>;

/**
 * \brief Класс наследуется от базового шаблонного класса ControlBase
 */
class WQUERY_API Button : public ControlBase<Button>
{
```

А в .cpp пишу примерно такую реализацию конструктора:

```
Button::Button(Window * window):ControlBase(this){}
```

**В итоге:**

Я могу взывать функции объектов-наследников по цепочке, и унаследованные от базового класса функции, вызванные таким образом, возвращают указатель именно на объект наследника. Теперь нет необходимости в каждом новом классе-наследнике переопределять эти методы, чтобы они возвращали правильный указатель. Не знаю, правильный ли это подход и стоило ли вообще, с точки зрения адекватной разработки на С/С++ запариваться о каких-то там "цепных вызовах", но вот такое вот сработало...

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD